# What hash algorithm is used in Bitcoin Cash?

Tags: proof-of-work

I know that bitcoin uses hashcash as PoW algorithm, Ethereum uses EtHash and Litecoin uses Scrypt. But I didn't found anywhere the PoW algorithm used in BitCoin Cash, does it uses hashcash too?

Comment: I would assume so since it was a hard fork from Bitcoin and was billed at one point as 'the real Bitcoin". Changing the PoW algorithm i think would have made that argument silly. I could be wrong and they did change, it just doesn't seem likely to me.

Answer (score 7):

BCH and BSV both use SHA256 as their POW algorithm, as does Bitcoin (BTC).